# How to create a polygon from other polygon boundaries?

Tags: qgis, open-source-gis, polygon, algorithm, polygon-creation

I want to write an algorithm that creates a polygon inside a hole made by a set of other polygons.  It's something like a [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) and it's like the "boundary" tool in Autocad.

The image shows an example: the algoritm should fill the enclosed white space in the center (after a click on it).

Any theory, pseudocode or examples would help a lot.

[image]

Comment: do you have a particular software in mind that you like to run the tool within (or any open source software)?

Comment: The idea is to create a Python plugin for Qgis.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the geoprocessing tools->symmetric difference from the QGIS 1.7 ftools plugin. Use as second layer a vector file with a polygon covering all the area you need.